# Can the Windows Indexing Service restart an app pool if it doesn't index the Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, indexing-service

I am having a slight debate with a colleague of mine on this subject.

Scenario:
A web site has a sub directory that is indexed using the Windows Indexing Service.  There is not a web.config in this directory and the indexing service is not indexing the parent directory which is the site root.  Something is causing the app pool to restart at supposedly random times.

From what I am finding online, the only time the Windows Indexing service would cause an app pool restart is if it's indexing the web.config (or machine.config).  My colleague is saying that the indexing service is causing the restarts just because it's in a child folder of the root.

So...does anyone have any information or experience on this?  If the indexing service is indexing a child folder of the root but not the root directory itself, can it cause IIS to restart the site's app pool?

EDIT:
The sub directory in question is NOT the bin directory.  I know it would cause such as well; however, the bin directory is not the target of the indexing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran some tests on this and it would appear that the indexing service does not touch any directory above the directory it's pointed at.